# Retrieve results JAX-RS + Jersey + Jackson

Tags: jackson, jersey, jax-rs, java-ee-7

I have this entity class

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name="user")
@NamedQuery(name="User.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM User u")
public class User implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id_user", unique=true, nullable=false)
private String idUser;

@Column(nullable=false, length=50)
private String docnum;

@Column(nullable=false, length=50)
private String email;

@Column(nullable=false, length=50)
private String firstname;

@Column(nullable=false, length=50)
private String lastname;

@Column(nullable=false, length=45)
private String pwd;

//bi-directional many-to-many association to Transaction
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name="transaction_users"
    , joinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="user", nullable=false)
        }
    , inverseJoinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="transaction", nullable=false)
        }
    )
private List<Transaction> transactions;

public User() {
}

public String getIdUser() {
    return this.idUser;
}

public void setIdUser(String idUser) {
    this.idUser = idUser;
}

public String getDocnum() {
    return this.docnum;
}

public void setDocnum(String docnum) {
    this.docnum = docnum;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return this.email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return this.firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return this.lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public List<Transaction> getTransactions() {
    return this.transactions;
}

public void setTransactions(List<Transaction> transactions) {
    this.transactions = transactions;
}
```

}

generated from a database table. Then i have this rest service

```
@Path("service/2.0")
public class ServiceTest {
@GET
@Path("/users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public Response getUser() {
    EntityManager entityManager = EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManager(); 
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin(); 
    Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<User> listOfUser = q.getResultList();  
    System.out.print(listOfUser);
    return Response.ok(listOfUser).build();
}
```

I'm (supposed) to be using the jackson API to handle json but i'm not using maven. For this reason, i've added in my buildpath the following .jars:

- jackson-annotations-2.9.3.jar
- jackson-core-2.9.3.jar
- jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar
- jackson-jaxrs-base-2.9.3.jar
- jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.9.3.jar
- jersey-media-json-jackson-2.26.jar
- jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.9.3.jar

Then i have an ApplicationConfig.java class

```
package prova;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.*;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public ApplicationConfig() {
        packages("com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json");
        packages("prova");
    }
}
```

When i try to submit a GET request with postman, i obtain an "HTTP 500 internal server error" with the description:

"The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request."

While from the eclipse console i can see

```
[EL Fine]: sql: 2017-12-16 17:44:54.251--ServerSession(1869059368)--
Connection(771012214)--Thread(Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-80,5,main])--
SELECT id_user, DOCNUM, EMAIL, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, PWD FROM user
[prova.User@3c713cb0, prova.User@49e51730, prova.User@d9ecdd7, 
prova.User@383fe468]dic 16, 2017 5:44:54 
PM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWr
iterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
GRAVE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, 
type=class java.util.Vector, genericType=class java.util.Vector.
```

So what i can deduce is that the query is correctly executed and it returns an array of 4 object (prova is the name of my entity manager) but then i have the GRAVE:MessageBodyWriter Error
What the hell i'm not doing correctly?why i can not retrieve my JSON data?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Following the advice, i've modified the GET resource into

```
@GET
@Path("/users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getUser() {

    return String.valueOf(10+4);

}
```

and submitting the GET request gives me the expected JSON answer from Postman "14"....

Can the problem be the conversion of a List into Json?if yes, what to do?

Thanks

**UPDATE 2**

I've edited the code of the REST resource in this way:

```
@GET
@Path("/users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getUser() {
    EntityManager entityManager = EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u");    
    List<User> listOfUser = q.getResultList();      
    System.out.print(listOfUser);

    if (listOfUser.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("VOID LIST");    
        entityManager.close();
        return String.valueOf(2);
    }
    for (User user : listOfUser) {
        System.out.println(user.getFirstname());
        System.out.println("---");         
    }
    return String.valueOf(3);
    }
```

The postman Output is "3" so, everything fine while the consoloe output is:

```
[EL Fine]: sql: 2017-12-17 13:48:33.214--ServerSession(286337061)--
Connection(2132504260)--Thread(Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--
SELECT id_user, DOCNUM, EMAIL, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, PWD FROM USER
[prova.User@2d3017ff, prova.User@6361d00, prova.User@7ab0944a, 
prova.User@5945162f]

matteo
---
tony
---
bruce
---
peter
---
```

which is perfectly consistent with what i have in the table of the DB... :(

Comment: I strongly suggest divide and conquer. You are using both JPA and JAX-RS.  Make your `@GET` method return a constant string: `public String getUser() { return "test"; }` and check if that works. If it does JAX-RS is mostly fine. Then do the JPA stuff but don't use them anywhere to eliminate a pure JPA issue. If it works it's probably a JSON issue. Try and post back your tests and results.

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: Alright, JAX-RS is clean. JPA now: are all the calls up to and including `getResultList()` give correct results? Does `listOfUser` contain what it's supposed to contain?

Comment: Also, what is `Transaction` in `User`? If it's just another POJO then remove it so we can eliminate that as a source of the problem.

Comment: editet the question again to include the test you suggested :)

Comment: I don't know what's the JPA message exactly, but it looks like it's working fine, perhaps just an INFO level. That means that the 2nd part is definitely an issue with Jersey not being able to write to JSON form. Try to create a `User` yourself and return that. You still didn't say what `Transaction` is so I suggest removing it for the test. Then add it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your response entity in an array of users. There is proper equivalent for array in json.

Other way ist to have a wrapper class for your list of users.

```
@XmlType
@XmlRootElement
class Wrapper {
  @XmlElement
  List<User> users;
}
```

Return this in your response.